# Error 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' when fetching from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Trying to fetch data from the currently signed-in user, I have gotten it to work without involving users but I am implementing a profile system. I am getting the error 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context', on the line:

`guard let documents = snap?.documents else {`

```
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }
         
        db.document(uid).addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            guard let documents = snap?.documents else {
                print("No workouts")
                return
            }
            
            self.userRoutines =  documents.compactMap({ q -> UserRoutine? in
                return try? q.data(as: UserRoutine.self)
            })
        }
```

I made sure the data model conformed to `Identifiable`:

```
   struct UserRoutine: Identifiable, Codable {
        @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
        var uid: String
        var email: String
        var routineName: String
        var numberOfWorkouts: Int
        var workoutName: String
        var sets: Int
        var reps: Int
        var weight: String
        var workoutName2: String
        var sets2: Int
        var reps2: Int
        var weight2: String
        var workoutName3: String
        var sets3: Int
        var reps3: Int
        var weight3: String
        var workoutName4: String
        var sets4: Int
        var reps4: Int
        var weight4: String
        var workoutName5: String
        var sets5: Int
        var reps5: Int
        var weight5: String
        var workoutName6: String
        var sets6: Int
        var reps6: Int
        var weight6: String
        var workoutName7: String
        var sets7: Int
        var reps7: Int
        var weight7: String
        var workoutName8: String
        var sets8: Int
        var reps8: Int
        var weight8: String
        var workoutName9: String
        var sets9: Int
        var reps9: Int
        var weight9: String
        var workoutName10: String
        var sets10: Int
        var reps10: Int
        var weight10: String
    }
```

Comment: Try specifying the type of "documents" you are expecting to receive, something like `guard let documents = snap?.documents as? [Document] else {`

Answer (score 1):

We've [recently](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) added a method to specify the type when mapping documents:

```swift
private func fetchBook(documentId: String) {
  let docRef = db.collection("workouts").document(documentId)
  
  docRef.getDocument(as: UserRoutine.self) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let userRoutine):
      // A UserRoutine value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
      self.userRoutine = userRoutine
      self.errorMessage = nil
    case .failure(let error):
      // A UserRoutine value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
      self.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
  }
}
```

To use this, make sure to upgrade to Firebase 8.13.0

For a comprehensive guide to mapping Firestore documents to/from Swift, check out [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/).

Also, just a small nit: `Identifiable` is needed to make it easier to use your struct inside a `List` view, it is not required for mapping to/from Firestore using Codable. To make your models codable, you just have to conform them to the `Codable` protocol.

Another thing I'd like to point out: try to use an [auth state change listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state). I am working on a blog post about this topic, should go live in a couple of days.